Find speed by using device accelerometer sensor
Is it possible to create an app on Android Studio to find the speed by only using the device's accelerometer and not using GPS? For example, an app to find the speed of a person walking.
Using the formula V = a * t and V2 = V1 + a*t, it seems possible if I also have time data.
However, how do I implement this in code?

Would you assume initial velocity (V0)?  Without initial velocity, your V (which you likely meant V1) is just change in velocity and instead should be V0 + (a*t), etc.

V = a * t is to show what I derived from a=V/t while V2 = V1 + a*t is the full equation. Here, my initial velocity would be V1. However, I agree that it would be better if I labeled it as V0 and V2 as V1.
